# Content type aware in sidebar template

Tags: theming

I've added some image and link content to region-sidebar.tpl.php before it executes the print $content. All good, except now the client wants the images and links specific to content type. (I can't do it all in CSS, otherwise i'd go that route).

How can I test for content type in region-sidebar.tpl.php or have a variable that is set. The region-sidebar.tpl.php doesn't see a variable defined in preprocess_node.

In region-sidebar.tpl.php I need something like:

```
<?php if ($content): 
  if ($mycontent_type == "foo") {
       ?> < add some html stuff here> <?php
  } 
  print $content; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current node like this:

```
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  if ($node->type == 'foo') {
    ...
  }
```

But don't put that logic directly in a template file - move it out to a preprocess function instead.

Comment: You're saying, in the theme's template file, add a preprocess_region function with the above? By referencing the $node variable, if it isn't created at this point, it gets created? So in the region-sidebar template file, it i could then reference it? I could add custom variables to it, like $variables?

Comment: Yep exactly - `menu_get_object()` should always give you the node object if you're on a node page, it'll be available in preprocess hooks

Comment: I'm ok testing in preprocess_region fn() for a sidebar region on a specific node type. All good, but then if i'm in the region-sidebar template file, it doesn't have access to $node. How do i set a varialble that i can test in there?